# Create Type as array unable to print array of V1.porttype

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TYPE PORTDETAIL_EX AS              
(  
    PortType VARCHAR(10),  
    PortStatus  VARCHAR(20),  
    UsedFlag VARCHAR(1)  
);  

CREATE TYPE PORTDETAILS AS             
(  
    portONTNumber VARCHAR(30),  
    portDetailsArray PORTDETAIL_EX[],  
    migratedLinesCount NUMERIC  
);
```

Comment: DO $$   
DECLARE   
V1 PORTDETAIL_EX;   
V2 PORTDETAIL_EX[];  
V3 PORTDETAILS;

BEGIN  
V1.PortType='QWERT';   
V1.PortStatus='ASDF';      
V1.UsedFlag='A';    
--v2 := ARRAY[(V1.PortType),(V1.PortStatus),(V1.UsedFlag)];

V2[1]:=ARRAY[(V1)];
V2[PortStatus]:=ARRAY[ASDFGG];
V2[UsedFlag]:=ARRAY[POIUY];

V3.portONTNumber := 'SRINI';
V3.portDetailsArray:= ARRAY[(V1.PortType),(V1.PortStatus),(V1.UsedFlag)];
V3.migratedLinesCount :=4;
  
RAISE notice '%', V1;
RAISE notice '%', V2[1];

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

Comment: Unable to print V2[1] Please help me above the anomonous block of code for testing

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in there rather than as a comment. I'm not going to bother to try to decypher that blob of text. And put details about the error, and what you're doing to get it.